# DYGRAPHS: Annotation on scatter point of the same date

Tags: annotations, dygraphs

In my scatter plot, there are points of the same date but i only want to annotate one. How can I specify that in my annotation data?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55ktaue1/2/)

```
g = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("container"),
"Date,Temperature\n" +
"2008-05-07,75\n" +
"2008-05-08,70\n" +
"2008-05-08,20\n" +
"2008-05-09,80\n"
 );
g.ready(function() {
g.setAnnotations([
{
  series: "Temperature",
  x: "2008-05-08",
  shortText: "L",
  text: "Coldest Day"
}
]);
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am dealing with a complete scatter graph. x vs y, and I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I ended up using decimal points to make mine work, so maybe you could add a second to your datapoint to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, by adding a second to your datapoint you don't want to be labeled.

https://jsfiddle.net/55ktaue1/3/

I would then use the formatting functionality to remove the timestamp from the date. 'legendFormatter' examples: http://dygraphs.com/tests/legend-formatter.html http://dygraphs.com/tests/labelsDateMilliseconds.html http://dygraphs.com/tests/labelsDateUTC.html

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("container"),
    "Date,Temperature\n" +
    "2008-05-07,75\n" +
    "2008-05-08,70\n" +
    "2008-05-08 00:00:01,20\n" +
    "2008-05-09,80\n"
  );

  g.ready(function() {
    g.setAnnotations([
    {
      series: "Temperature",
      x: "2008-05-08",
      shortText: "L",
      text: "Coldest Day"
    }
    ]);
  });
```